# Heterogeneity analysis for a randomised experiment

Tags: heterogeneity

Suppose that you are planning a randomised experiment and will estimate how effects vary with baseline covariates. One simple approach uses interactions. That is, if $Y_i$ denotes the outcome of interest, $T_i$ denotes the (let's assume binary) treatment that has been randomised, and $X_i$ denotes a baseline covariate, one estimates the regression
\begin{equation}
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 T_i + \beta_2 T_i X_i + u_i
\end{equation}
I have two questions about this:

1. If $X_i$ is continuous, should one first convert it to a binary variable (e.g. that equals 1 if $X_i$ exceeds its median)? The results of this exercise seem a bit easier to interpret since $\beta_2$ becomes the difference in treatment effects between the $X_i = 0$ and $X_i = 1$ groups. However, I don't think this is very standard.
2. Should one also include $X_i$ in the regression (above and beyond the interaction term)? I don't really why this is essential, although it does presumably add power.